# Uploading images with Jpeg on contact

Tags: images

I have a custom field on contact called " Image of contact"  where the users can upload their pictures. I have set the "Field Type" to be "Rich Text" since Rich Text allows .gif, .jpg, and .png file types.

Now, the issue with this is the users are not able to upload the files with "Jpeg" type. Is there a way through which I can make the"Jpeg" files to get uploaded through the same "Image of Contact (Rich text)" field I have created? or A formula which can convert "Jpeg to Jpg" or through a programmatic approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search produced this answer:

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000188392&language=en_US

[image]